# Notion of inner automorphisms for group schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-schemes, group-schemes

Let $G$ be a finite group scheme over the field $k$ ( you can assume $k$ is algebraically closed). I've seen the term "inner automorphisms" for $G$ at many places but I still don't understand what the correct definition. Suppose, we have a automorphism $f:G \to G$. This is means we have an automorphism $f_R:G(R) \to G(R)$ for every $k$-algebra $R$. So, $f$ is an inner-automorphism if $F_R$ is an inner-automorphism for every $k$-algebra $R$?

Also, is there a simpler definition? Or simpler way to think about it? Is it enough to say just $f_k$ is an inner-automorphism?

Also, any kind of reference on this topic would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for any $g$ in $G(k)$ one has a morphism $c_g:G\to G$ given on $R$-points by $c_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$ which makes sense since $g\in G(k)\subseteq G(R)$. An automorphism of the form $c_g$ is called a *naive inner automorphism* of . Of course, if you replace $k$ by a ring nothing changes.

If $k$ is algebraically closed one then defines an automorphism to be *inner* if it is of the form $c_g$ for $g\in G(k)$ (in other words if it is naively inner). If you now assume that $k$ is not necessarily algebraically closed things get slightly more complicated. Namely, note that the association $G\to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ which on $R$-points associates $g\in G(R)$ to the naive inner automorphism $c_g\in \mathrm{Aut}(G_R)$ certainly has kernel equal to $Z(G)$. Thus, we get an induced injection $G^\mathrm{ad}:=G/Z(G)\hookrightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(G)$. One then defines an automorphism of $G$ to be *inner* if its in the image of the map $G^\mathrm{ad}(k)\to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$. If $k$ is not algebraically closed then this is strictly larger than the set $c_g$ for $g\in G(k)$ since the map $G(k)\to G^\mathrm{ad}(k)$ needn't be surjective (e.g. think about $G=\mathrm{GL}_n$!). Intuitively, the inner automorphisms of $G$ are then those of the form $c_g$ for $g\in G(\overline{k})$ such that $c_g$ stabilizes $G(k)\subseteq G(\overline{k})$.

As an example of this phenomenon, one can note that $\begin{pmatrix}0 & i\\ i & 0\end{pmatrix}$ is an element of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ and so gives an automorphism of $\text{SL}_{2,\mathbb{Q}}$ which is inner, but is not of the form $c_g$ for $g\in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$. Namely, note that

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & i\\ i & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & i\\ i & 0\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}d & c\\ b & a\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I think the second definition you gave should actually end up being equivalent to the OP's functorial definition (an automorphism which is inner on $R$-points for all $R$), and the OP's definition generalizes to arbitrary bases. Does that sound right?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Suppose that you have an element $\phi$ of $G^\mathrm{ad}(k)$. Then, as we said, $\phi$ gives an automorphism of $G(k)$. Is this 'inner' in the classical sense? I don't think so, but maybe I'm misinterpretting what you're asking.

Comment: The issue I think is that the association which takes $R$ to the inner automorphisms of $G(R)$ is not a sheaf. Its sheafification is something like $G^\mathrm{ad}$. In particular, this sheafification contains 'more' automorphisms than just the ones that are inner for all $R$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The generalization for all basies is merely that we have a morphism of sheaves $G\to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ for a group scheme $G$ over any base $X$. This then has kernel $Z(G)$ by definition, and so gives a factorization through $G^\mathrm{ad}:G/Z(G)$--the quotient (fppf) **sheaf**--and one then defines the inner automorphims of $G$ over $Y$ to the image of $\mathrm{G}^\mathrm{ad}(Y)\to \mathrm{Aut}(G_Y)$.

Comment: Oh, okay, so we want automorphisms that become inner on a sufficiently fine cover? ("Locally inner"?) Hmm. Thanks!